# Automated tests not executing in UFT except first one

Tags: batch-file, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft, hp-quality-center

We have a tests campaign which is supposed to be launched automatically (by Windows tasks scheduler). It used to work, but now for some reason only the first test of the first test set gets executed.

The tests are defined in **QC** (ALM) and runned by **VBS** scripts in **UFT**. 
Windows tasks scheduler runs a .bat file which itself calls the VBS scripts.
The problem doesn't come from the tasks scheduler, since we have the same result if we run manually the .bat file.

Does anyone already had this problem with UFT/QTP ?

Comment: Has anything changed on the system since you last successfully ran the tests? Has the batch file changed at all?

Comment: The batch file didn't change. I didn't make any change to the system, but there can be updates from time to time made by the administrators.

Comment: Hint for debugging: force `echo on` in your `.bat` script and append `pause` to see batch  behaviour.

Comment: May be try to verify QtpAutomation - remoteagent settings. Are all timeouts proper?

Comment: @JosefZ : I tried but there is a batch file calling another one which calls another one which calls a vbs script via SysWOW64\cscript.exe... and I couldn't get any message...

Comment: @Vwaib : the timeout parameters seem ok.

Comment: Today, the automatic campaign has run again... I don't know why. Anyway, we will be switching tools soon, and we will use XStudio/Selenium/Python instead of QC/UFT/VBS...